# Having homes in both UK & Switzerland

Tags: residency

I am UK resident, retired with a house in the UK. I am engaged to a Swiss national who is still living & working in Switzerland. Before Corona, we simply commuted back & forward so had no problems with 90 day rules. Since the lock down I've remained in Switzerland and now wish to stay beyond 90 days. Does anyone have experience of whether this is possible & if so, how? For example, people with a second home in Switzerland that they visit for more than 90 days.

It seems that I could register as a person not seeking work provided that I take out health care insurance but I'm not sure what impact this would have on my UK status. After Corona, I will go back to spending more time in the UK than Switzerland. Does anyone have experience of being registered in Switzerland while retaining a home in the UK?

Comment: You can live abroad and still be a UK resident for tax https://www.gov.uk/tax-uk-income-live-abroad/uk-resident You may lose UK residency if you’re away from the UK for more than 2 years https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/period-that-individuals-may-be-outside-the-uk-without-losing-their-indefinite-leave-to-remain/period-that-individuals-are-allowed-to-be-outside-the-uk-without-losing-their-indefinite-leave-to-remain